# Graphing the inequality $M = \{(x,y)| x^2 - y^2 \geq 0\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im having trouble solving the following problem:

Graph the inequality $M = \{(x,y)| x^2 - y^2 \geq 0\}$.

After looking at wolfram alpha i know the solution, but still, i can't grasp the thought process behind solving the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple way to look at it would be to brute force it for all cases of $x, y$ being $<, > 0$

Comment: You draw the graph of $x^2-y^2=0$. This divides the plane into various regions. You shade those where $x^2-y^2>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequality $$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)\geq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2-y^2 \geq 0 \iff x^2 \geq y^2 \iff \sqrt{x^2} \geq \sqrt{y^2} \iff |x| \geq |y|$$

There are $4$ cases: $A: x, y \geq 0; B: x \geq 0 \geq y; C: y \geq 0 \geq x; D: 0 \geq x,y$.

In the case $A$: $|x| \geq |y| \iff x \geq y$; in the case $B$: $|x| \geq |y| \iff x \geq -y$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First graph the equality:  $y^2=x^2,$ i.e., $y=\pm x$.  These lines divide the plane into four regions.

Test a point inside each region -- say $(0,1), (1,0), (0, -1)$, and $(-1,0)$ --

to see which regions are included in the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y) \ge 0$ draw the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ and then check which region satisfies the inequality by choosing a point from each angle.