# Graphing $(x+y) \div (x-y) \ge 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im having problem graphing the following inequality: 
$(x+y) \div (x-y) \ge 0$. 
I know what the graph looks like, but I can't grasp the thought process behind solving the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271636/graphing-the-inequality-m-x-y-x2-y2-geq-0)

Answer (score 2):

First of all it must be $$x\neq y$$- So, now we have two cases:
$$x>y$$ then we get $$x\geq -y$$
Second case:
$$x<y$$ then we get $$x\le-y$$

Answer (score 0):

First consider points with $x-y>0$. Here we need $x+y>0$ and this translates into $-x <y<x$. These are points between the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ with $x >0$. Similary taking $x-y<0$ we get points with $x <0$ and $(x,y)$ between the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$